# how to retrieve selected data from database based on selected checkbox in proper JSON format for highcharts

Tags: json, checkbox, highcharts

sorry for disturbing...I got json format to build column highcharts that will accept data from user multiple selected via checkbox and *retrieve the data result from database based on what they check at checkbox and display by highcharts in form of column chart..*

The problem is,I think my json format for column highcharts is not correct can anyone see my code and tell me what wrong with this....below this is the json output and the code..:- Thank u very much for your time..

Let say if I checked 2 checkbox from the checkboxes list (BAT123 & BIO22), this json will displayed like this:

```
[{"name":"Subject","data":["BAT123"]},{"name":"Result","data":[3.03]}]
[{"name":"Subject","data":["BAT123","BIO222"]},{"name":"Result","data":[3.03,1.05]}]
```

I know that json format is wrong, I tried to fixed it but still failed..I am a newbie..hope u can try to fix my code below.

Here is the json code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['iddoc'])) //iddoc is the value from selected checkbox
{
        $category = array();
        $category['name'] = 'Subject';


        $series1 = array();
        $series1['name'] = 'Result';


        foreach ($_GET['iddoc'] as $iddoc)
        {

            $query="select * from compareresult where iddocument=$iddoc";
            $sql_query = mysql_query($query) or die('Error 3 :'.mysql_error());         
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) 
            {
                 $category['data'][] = $r['subject'];
                 $series1['data'][] = $r['result'];

            }   
            $result = array();
            array_push($result,$category);
            array_push($result,$series1);
            $jsonTable = json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
            echo $jsonTable; 
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: right now I am not using mysqli because I saw the example in mysql form but after I'm clear with this I will change it to mysqli..

Comment: Your data points need to number not string as you have.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I'm still not getting it..I'm so sorry :( .. I am quite slow.. :(

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @SebastianBochan no error, but the highcharts wont come out..so i knew my json format was not correct..

Comment: We need to live demo to check, because we cannot replicate it.

Comment: @SebastianBochan ooo..really..?you mean like put it into the fiddle?how i am gonna to live demo it because the data was come from my database...

Comment: I mean live demo anywhere.